# Trouble reinstalling mysql on OSX Mavericks

Tags: mysql, sql, database, macos, terminal

I'm trying to reinstall mysql on my computer (os x mavericks) and I've done the following with the following errors:

```
bash <(curl -Ls http://git.io/eUx7rg)
```

Error:

```
Starting MySQL
... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/christians-mbp.saumag.edu.pid).
/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server: line 362: pidof: command not found
/dev/fd/63: line 119: SORRY, MySQL IS NOT RUNNING ... THERE MUST BE A PROBLEM: command not found
```

So I decided to see uninstall it if it was already there:

```
brew uninstall mysql
bash <(curl -Ls http://git.io/eUx7rg)
```

This says that mysql is currently still installed, so I did the following:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
edit /etc/hostconfig and remove the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*

bash<(curl -Ls http://git.io/eUx7rg)
```

This gave me the same error messages as before, So I decided to redo all the rm commands above, including the edit and run the following commands:

```
ps -ax | grep mysql
brew cleanup
sudo rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
brew doctor
brew update
brew install mysql
unset TMPDIR
mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`yyttr3` --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
```

After the last command I got the following error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/my_print_defaults
  Reason: image not found
FATAL ERROR: Neither host 'christians-mbp.saumag.edu' nor 'localhost' could be looked     up with
 /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/resolveip
Please configure the 'hostname' command to return a correct
```

hostname.
    If you want to solve this at a later stage, restart this script
    with the --force option

I don't really know what the problem is, i'm not sure if i'm even installing it right. From what I have read this should be a good way to install mysql. If you have any ideas on what I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sure you've solved this by now, but I just had the same problem.  For anyone else who stumbles across this:

For me, it was an issue with OpenSSL.

```
resolveip `hostname`
```

If it says OpenSSL isn't loaded,

```
brew uninstall openssl
brew install openssl
```

then try again.  Hope this helps.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me as well.

Comment: If someone else still have problems after doing this, check this thread https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/25665 I solved by replacing `/usr/bin/install_name_tool` with the version from Xcode.app and reinstalling openssl and mysql with homebrew

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Only solution that I found is to install mysql from source code. The reason for this error to occur and how to solve it is explained in full detail in the following link: http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.com.au/2010/08/mysql-installation-error-neither-host.html

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was agree XCODE terms by opening XCODE. That fixed everything.