# Trouble reinstalling mysql on Mac OSX 10.7

Tags: openssl

I have just install mysql by "brew install mysql".  Then I typed mysql and it gave me the below error.

```
myjeans$ mysql
dyld: Library not loaded:     
@@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mysql
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5

myjeans$ which mysql
/usr/local/bin/mysql
```

I have found a similar problem as this link
"[Trouble reinstalling mysql on OSX Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23027880/trouble-reinstalling-mysql-on-osx-mavericks)" and tried the;

```
resolveip `hostname`
brew uninstall openssl
brew install openssl
```

but it still gives me the same error... Also uninstall & installed mysql several times... Of course I have Xcode installed in my MAC.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this problem! The main problem was because I did not have enough HD space, the "brew" installation did not complete!! Cleaned my HD and uninstalled & installed mysql and complete!!

If you ever get this error, remember to check the last line in the terminal. It should be as below (if not, installation is not complete!)

```
To connect:
mysql -uroot

To have launchd start mysql at login:
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load mysql now:
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
mysql.server start
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.22: 9665 files, 347M, built in 8.2 minutes
```